# I cant able to show wrapper class result in visualforce page table

Tags: apex, visualforce

Apex Class :

```
public with sharing class myquestionspage {

public List<parsequestionjson> listquestion{get; set;}
Public myquestionspage(){
String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();
User activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = : userName limit 1];
String userEmail = activeUser.Email;
system.debug(userEmail);
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http(); 
        req.setMethod('POST'); // Method Type
        req.setEndpoint('http://nicomatic.com/test_forum/process/post.php?auth=ay5wZXJuYW1pdHRhQG5pY29tYXRpYy5pbg==&action=user_questions&var1=base64_enc&var2=base64_enc&var3=base64_enc'); // Server Url
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); // Content Type
        //try {
            res = http.send(req);
            //string response=res.getBody();
            system.debug(res.getBody());     
                 listquestion = (List<parsequestionjson>) JSON.deserializeStrict(res.getBody(),List<parsequestionjson>.class);                
  }  
public class parsequestionjson{   
public String postid;    
public String categoryid;  
public String title;   
public String content;  
public String tags;    
public String created;  
public String updated;   
public String upvotes;   
public String downvotes;   
public String netvotes;   
public String views;  
 }
}
```

Visualforce page :

```
<apex:page controller="myquestionspage" >
{!listquestion}
<apex:form>
<table>
 <apex:repeat value="{!listquestion}" var="a" > 
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!a.categoryid}</td>                                                
                        </tr>    
                    </apex:repeat>
   </table>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

For above {!listquestion} its is displaying this data :

```
[parsequestionjson:[categoryid=3, content=<p>I'm&nbsp;<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?pv90=1&amp;pv69=80&amp;pv589=25&amp;FV=fff40016%2Cfff802f3%2C70078c%2C1640001&amp;mnonly=0&amp;newproducts=0&amp;ColumnSort=0&amp;page=1&amp;quantity=0&amp;ptm=0&amp;fid=0&amp;pageSize=25">shopping</a>&nbsp;for some bulk male header pins and noticed a&nbsp;<strong><em>lot</em></strong>&nbsp;of options for the contact length column. I know 1" is a longer pin than I'm used to and 0.1" is too short, but is there a standard length for these parts, or a fairly standard range of lengths?</p><p>I guess for many applications, it's not gonna matter, but when I'm buying a lot of them, they'd better be the right length!</p><p>Breadboards are the main target for these headers.</p><p><span style="color:rgb(36, 39, 41); font-family:verdana,bitstream vera sans,dejavu sans,tahoma,geneva,arial,sans-serif">The pins it mates&nbsp;with are Breadboards, and standard female headers, mostly. (female headers don't seem to specify a contact length)</span></p>, created=2016-10-26 14:51:50, downvotes=0, netvotes=0, postid=6, tags=contact-length,male-connectors, title=Standard length of male header pins, updated=2016-10-26 14:54:23, upvotes=0, views=2], parsequestionjson:[categoryid=1, content=answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1 answer 1, created=2016-11-08 08:48:36, downvotes=0, netvotes=0, postid=7, tags=jumper-wires,contact-length, title=question 1 question 1 question 1 question 1, updated=2016-11-11 07:03:35, upvotes=0, views=1]]
```

The problem is i cant able to display this data on visualforce table :

It is showing error as this : Error: Unknown property

> 'myquestionspage.parsequestionjson.categoryid'

i dont know why it is not displaying table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add getters and setters to the properties of parsequestionjson i.e.

```
public class parsequestionjson{   
    public String postid {get; set;}   
    public String categoryid {get; set;}
    //etc...
}
```